# C++ fstream isn't opening a file

Tags: c++

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my code? why doesn't read the "hello";

```cpp
fstream filename;
    
char data[100] = "hello";
filename.open("filename.txt",ios::in);
if (! filename.is_open()) {
    return 1;
}
filename >> data;
filename.close();
```

Comment: do `std::perror("hello");` just before `return 1;` to find what is the root cause. Info will be printed into stderr.

Comment: How did you find out that it does not read "hello" from disk? The variable contains "hello" before and contains "hello" after reading from disk. How did you distinguish them?

Comment: Are you sure you want to _read_ `hello` instead of _writing_ it to the file?

Comment: Where want you read?

Comment: The usual reason for not finding a file is that that the file is in another directory. Try using the full path instead of just the file name.